# Provide a clause set representation of a formula in CNF with a minimal number of clauses which is semantically equivalent to the KV map provided.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

$KV$ map:

[image: KV map]

So far I have tried brute forcing to generate a CNF formula, but that obviously doesn't give me the minimal CNF. I am left with $6$ sets with $4$ elements each and I can't simplify them.

Please also provide the steps to the solution. Thank you.